# In-app purchase was successful, however, it did not run my code.Why?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am new to in-app purchase system. I just watched some tutorials, then implemented in-app purchase. However, when my in-app purchase was successful, it did not run my code. Does it have to run the following code?:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                writeInApp("1");
                playGroundMain.bonus_pop_up(R.drawable.rich_big, "\"VIP Монстр\"");
                playGroundMain.reWriteBonus("1", 6);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a fair few apps with the payment system, you should take a look at this listener

```java
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener()
    {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. JSON: " + purchase.getOriginalJson() + ", signature: " + purchase.getSignature());

            if (mHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isSuccess())
            {
                    Log.i(TAG, "BOUGHT THE ITEM :-)")
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while consuming: " + result);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
        }
    };
```

you could add this listener in the consumeAsync function of the IabHelper like so:

```java
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() 
{
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
        {

            if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_21500))
            {
                // bought 21500 credits
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is 21500 credits. Starting credits consumption.");
                try
                {
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
                }
                catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error consuming 21500 credits. Another async operation in progress.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And then you can put the "mPurchaseFinishedListener" in the "launchPurchaseFlow " function as so:

```java
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(activity, item, REQUEST_CODE, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
```

REQUEST_CODE being 10001

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Emiel van Essen  Thanks man, you saved my life!!))))) But I have a little problem, when user do not want to buy in app and cancels the "google buy pop up display", my app crashes, it exits. Can you tell me what is a bug?

Comment: @IriskulTurduev Could you send me the crash report?

Comment: @ Emiel van Essen    Now it does not crash, because I add "if (purchase == null) return;" line of code into IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener method

Comment: @IriskulTurduev ah, nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a non-consumable inapp purchase the code is fine.

When doing test purchases sometimes the `onActivityResult()` does not gets called. In a real purchase this may not happen.

To handle the purchase in that case you have to check `result code == user already owns this item //resultCode 7`, so that the user will not have to pay again in a situation like this.